# 'nvcc' is not recognized by VS code terminal but works in the CMD prompt

Tags: visual-studio-code, cuda

When I run "nvcc --version" in the CMD it gives the version but in the VS code, it says 'nvcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

My guess is this is something to do with environment variables but don't know how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you see when you `echo %PATH%` in your cmd window, and in the VS Code integrated terminal? How do they compare? Please [edit] to show that info.

Answer (score 2):

closing the powershell window & reopen it again will solve this. You could also close & reopen visual studio code to achieve the same thing